# Axios not receiving cookies in Heroku deployed MERN application

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, cookies, axios

I have a Node/Express server deployed on Heroku that I am using to send httpOnly cookies to store JWTs. I have been using Axios to set the cookies while hosting my React app on port 3000 and the Express server on port 5000.

**Axios Config in React App**

```
const myAxios = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/",
});
```

**index.js of Express App**

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
```

This has been working fine until I deployed my app to Heroku and switched my Axios config to use `baseURL:http://app-name.herokuapp.com`. I am now no longer receiving cookies (for both GET and POST requests). I still get the cookies if I visit http://app-name.herokuapp.com/get-cookie-endpoint directly in Chrome or in Postman. However, when I try calling `myAxios.get('/get-cookie-endpoint)` from my React app on localhost:3000, I no longer receive the cookie. I inspected the XHR request and I am still getting a Set-Cookie response header.

Any ideas? I have experimented with many different Axios and CORS settings but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `sameSite = 'none';` in cookie object. I was having this issue and it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to elaborate a little more on your answer. How does it work? Why do you think this solves OP's issues?